# How to use the custom neural network function in the MATLAB for images

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I have to make a simple 3 layer neural network in Matlab (2-10-2).

I have worked on Convolution Neural Network in Matlab and want to compare that with simple neural network architecture.

I have 14000 images of each class and there are two classes at the input and two classes will be at the output. Image size at the input in 56x56=3136.
1) How to make 2-10-2 NN architecture.

2) Also the images i have are RGB so its `56x56x3` so input matrix will be 9408?Regarding in the input `x` if two classes. for each class x1 will have the size 3161x700 and x2 will have the size 9408x700, the `x` input will have the final size of `9408x1400` and label will be `1x1400`?

Comment: @Cody Gray. Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the feedforwardnet [MATLAB help page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html) there is this example:

```
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
net = feedforwardnet(10);
net = train(net,x,t);
view(net)
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,y,t)
```

This is almost what you want. The feedforwardnet can take an array of different hidden layer sizes, so we can do:

```
    net = feedforwardnet([2 10 2]);
```

to get the architecture you want. You don't need to worry about the input layer size or output layer sizes. Those are set to '0' and automatically set to the right size based on the inputs and outputs you provide to the network (`net` in the example) during training. In your case, you can reshape your 56x56 matrix into a 3136x1 vector:

```
x = reshape(x,3161,1);
```

So, following the above example, make sure your class/target labels are in `t` and your corresponding inputs in `x` and you're good to go.

That being said, I would not use one of these networks to classify images. ConvNets are generally the way to go.

To split the input data (x and t) into training, validation and test sets and have the training function automatically take care of generalization ability like that, do this before training:

```
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 0.7;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 0.15;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0.15;
```

Putting it together, we have:

```
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
net = feedforwardnet(10);
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 0.7;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 0.15;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0.15;
net = train(net,x,t);
view(net)
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,y,t)
```

Comment: Martin, I understand for the `feedforwardnet`. 
1) Regarding in the input `x` if two classes. for each class `x1` will have the size `3161x700` and `x2` will have the size `3161x700` is it correct?
2) how we much data will be used for training and validation? how can I divide that
3) The testing data will similar to the input like `3161x100` for each class how to do testing?

Comment: See my updated answer. The trick is to use the built in divideFcn which divides your training data up according the proportions you give it.

Comment: Martin I have updated my question, the is being answered. just have some confusion with the second part. if you please update your question

Comment: You need to make sure the two classes x1 and x2 have the same number of features (say 9408) if you want them to train a single model for both classes - which is probably a good idea, as there will likely be correlations between the features of the two classes that can be modeled by the NN. You *can* train two separate neural nets if the number of features varies, though. But yes, if you have 9408x1400, then 9408 will be your inputs (say pixels values) and 1400 will be your number of examples. Does that explain your 2nd question sufficiently well?

Answer (score -3):

For 2 class classification problem single output logistic neuron is enough.
NN architecture of (2-10-1) would be enough.

Comment: I understand for the feedforwardnet. 1) Regarding in the input x if two classes. for each class x1 will have the size 3161x700 and x2 will have the size 3161x700, is it correct? 2) how we much data will be used for training and validation? how can I divide that 3) The testing data will similar to the input like 3161x100 for each class how to do testing?

Comment: While this is true, a single output is enough to distinguish between two classes, there are benefits to having two separate output neurons. For one, having a softmax output on the two output neurons gives you a probabilistic output of how much it is like one class, normalized over all the class outputs.